# Adjustable image on top of an another image using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like for the image B to be fluid like the Image A, while mainlining it's center position of Image A.

Here is my sample code:

```
<div class="container">
 <img id="imgA" src="A.png" /> 
 <img id="imgB" src="B.png" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#imgA{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
}




#imgB{
    position: absolute; 
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -200px;
    margin-top: -100px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

With above code, I only can achieve image B to be the center of Image A while the resolution is high enough, but when it gets lower, image A will adjust to it's screen but image B remains the same. What do I need to add for image B to be fluid and be the center of image A at any resolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to calculate the offset of the second image in %, not in pixels, and make sure their sizes are relative to the container div. I created a js fiddle with an example: http://jsfiddle.net/BX6u7/

```
<div class="container">
 <img id="imgA" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" /> 
 <img id="imgB" src="http://placehold.it/150x50" />
</div>
```

and css:

```
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position:relative;
  width: 50%;
  background-color:yellow;
}

#imgA{
    display: block;
    width:100%;
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
    border:none;
}

#imgB{
    top: 28.6%;
    left: 21.6%;
    width: 57%;
    max-width: 57%;
    border:1px solid white;    
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using hard-coded `px` units, instead go for `%`.

Replace `margin,width and height` attributes with respective `%` values. '%' to be determined as per your image sizes and your requirement.